# How to register an authentication handler service in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I need to write a basic authentication handler. In my `onAuthenticationFailure`, just for testing, i'm var-dumping `$request`. it should work using bad credentials, but nothing happened.

I guess there is something wrong in my `src\Acme\TestBundle\resources\Config\services.yml`:

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
```

This is the test class, use statement removed for readability:

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Handler;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,
    AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface, LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
    }

    function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request,
        AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        var_dump($request);
        die();
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the handler in the [`security.yml`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) file:

```
form_login:
    success_handler: authentication_handler
    failure_handler: authentication_handler
logout:
    success_handler: authentication_handler
```